# in a text file, pick up lines after a certain "->" character only, ignore the lines before it

Tags: bash, awk, grep

how to pick up characters after a certain "->" only from a text file.

I have a file named `a.txt`. It has many many lines in the below format:

`/abc/def/ghi/jkl.txt->/mno/pqr/stu/vwy.txt`

1) I want to grep only the line after ">", How to do it?

2) I also want a way to print line before "->".

Expected output for case1) `/mno/pqr/stu/vwy.txt`

Expected output for case2) `/abc/def/ghi/jkl.txt`

Comment: add expected output for clarity.. looks like you need `/mno/pqr/stu/vwy.txt` as output.. if so, better use `cut/awk` for field based selection... you are also expected to show what you tried to solve this issue..

Comment: will this work? `grep -o '->.*'` also, i need to find a way for line before "->" @Sundeep

Comment: @Pompy, post the expected result for both cases

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest see the edited question.

Comment: looks like there is still doubts regarding the question.. `/abc/def/ghi/jkl.txt->/mno/pqr/stu/vwy.txt` is single line or multiple? two answers so far are assuming they are two different lines

Comment: also `grep -o '->.*'` would result in `->` as part of output.. in which case you need `grep -oP` or just use `awk` as it was intended for such cases

Comment: single line @Sundeep, anyway thanks, i got the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` seems to be a more useful tool than `grep` for this task:

So, to get the part before "->" you can use:

```
awk -F"->" '{print $1}' filename
```

And for the part after "->":

```
awk -F"->" '{print $2}' filename
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i needed. hmm,  i have to study `awk` more.

Comment: If i want to store the value in a variable of this: `a = (awk -F "->" '{print $2}' $line1)` , its throwing me error saying -F is not a command. line1 is a variable line from  `a.txt` file.

Comment: @Pompy - use `var=$(cmd)`, not `var=(cmd)`.

Comment: No @EdMorton, now the problem coming is that it look like awk doesnt take a path name, it takes only files or directories. But i want to awk a path, ie $line1 variable, which is a path given in my question.

Comment: @Pompy that has nothing to do with the error message you mentioned in your comment and which I addressed in mine.

Comment: yes, i know @EdMorton, but can you help me abou the problem which i mentioned above?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're referring to but it sounds like you might be changing your question. Don't do that as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691) aren't welcome in this forum - accept the answer to the question you asked and then ask a new question if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

First case:

```
grep -A1 "\->" --no-group-separator a.txt | grep -v "\->"
```

Second case:

```
grep -B1 "\->" --no-group-separator a.txt | grep -v "\->"
```

The `A1` and `B1` flags take the line after and before respectively, `--no-group-separator` ensures nothing between the lines, and `grep -v "\->"` removes the actual lines with `->`.